# Comparing large categorical data sets with low or zero counts

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, large-data, many-categories

I'm dealing with a biological feature which can be classified into $2^{20}$  categories. I also have two pretty large data sets of 1 and 3 million entries. Actually, only around 30 thousand categories were observed in the latter, and even less in the former. Thus, a lot of categories have zero counts, and a few have rather small ones.

I would like to tell whether the samples come from a different populations, i.e. compare the aforesaid feature distributions. The only test I can think of is Pearson's $\chi^2$, which is (to my knowledge) not applicable in the case of low counts.

Any advice (including literature on the subject) would be appreciated.

Comment: You can apply the *statstic* well enough (though its not the only choice of statistic); the question is whether that statistic really has a chi-square distribution.

Comment: The chi-squared test is probably not valid, so you might consider a Monte Carlo test instead.  Come up with some statistic for measuring the difference between these distributions, estimate the common distribution (under the null of both distributions being the same) using the total combined counts and then simulate lots of data sets and use the simulated distribution of your test statistic to formulate a rejection criterion.

Comment: Given that the number of categories is a power of 2, we might guess that the categories are obtained from combining the values of 20 binary response variables. The first step in any practical analysis would therefore be to observe the marginal counts for the 20 response variables for each dataset. A chisquare test would likely be a valid way to compare the marginal counts between the datasets for each response variable individually. If any of these markedly different, then it would settle the original question immediately without needing to consider all 2^20 categories.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand the problem but let me know if this is on the right track and I can get you some more feedback. Think of $2^{20}$ as the number of words in a dictionary. I give you two books, one which has 1 million words containing 30000 unique ones from the dictionary  and the other containing 3 million words and (say) 35000 unique ones from the dictionary. I give you a new set of words (is this what you mean by 'sample'?') and I want to know which book it came from?

If this is case..look up Naive Bayes classifier. It is the simplest one out there. It assumes conditional independence (given the book, words are independent). There are  It does exactly this. There are a lot of software which will fit these models for you. They all have the problem of zero or very small counts. They use a fix around this problem. A point to note that in these models, there is a fail safe..as in what if I observe a word I have not seen so far (i.e. a new one from the $2^{20}$). They call the probability of observing this probability of 'rest'. This means all the ones you do not observe in the training sample will fall into rest.

The accuracy usually falls in the 60% range as far as prediction goes. It is not fantastic but its a start. There are more complex models (look up Lexicalized PCFGs if you think it suits you better though these are very context specific). I strongly suggest you use pre-written software in case you want to use these models and curb the commonly observed urge to code up these dynamic programming problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In general, suggested direction seems right to me. The whole dictionary abstraction suits the problem well (to say, categories were obtained as a fixed-length words made up with 4-letter alphabet). I'd like to clarify things a bit. What I've meant by samples were the data sets themself, as they are obtained from a larger, potentially infinite populations. The samples (my data sets) are assumed to be representatives of their respective populations.

Comment: Proceeding with the dictionary abstraction, what I would like to do is to tell whether word usage differs significantly in the populations.

Comment: That is a multivariate goodness of fit idea. They extend the idea of Pearson Chi square in higher dimension using monte-carlo resampling..see for instance [this](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/gof.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to figure it out. As far as I understand, the basic idea behind this is testing original samples against permuted one, where data comes from the both samples. Is this correct?